# How can I run the vbscript as the 'Administrator' but access on APPDATA folder of current logon user VBSCRIPT

Tags: vbscript, appdata

I tried to access on the APPDATA folder, which does function with the following code perfectly (run as the current logon user):

```
Set objShellApp  = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Const ssfAPPDATA = &H1A
sAppDataPath = objShellApp.NameSpace(ssfAPPDATA).Self.Path
```

The result of sAppDataPath is: C:\Users\ **Peter** \AppData\Roaming

Now the problem is, I have to run the Script as the Administrator account. And if I run this script as the Administrator on Clients, than the result is allways following:
C:\Users\ **Administrator** \AppData\Roaming

How can I change that? I want, that he should take the Appdata folder path of the current logon user. In spite of running the script as the Administrator. And i have to run the script as Administrator because of some permission.

How can I realize that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot do this with a VBS alone.

You would need to create a batch file to pass this `%APPDATA%` environment variable into the script as Argument, then modify the VBS script to process this argument(s).

Sample below:

**UPDATE:**

If you do not mind people being able to open the batch file and know the password of the user account you intend to Run As, get [**psexec.exe** from MS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) with the updated batch file contents (assuming psexec.exe stored in `C:\SysInt\`):

**VBS File**

```
Dim sTxt
sTxt = WScript.Arguments.Count & " arguments passed into vbs:"
sTxt = sTxt & JoinArgs
wscript.echo sTxt

Function JoinArgs()
    Dim sTmp
    sTmp = ""
    For Each oArg In Wscript.Arguments
        sTmp = sTmp & vbCrLf & oArg
    Next
    JoinArgs = sTmp
End Function
```

**Batch File (UPDATED)**

```
@echo off
C:\SysInt\psexec.exe -u %computername%\administrator -p AccountPassword -e wscript.exe "c:\debug\vbs\test.vbs" %appdata%
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your sample doesn't work. If I run the batch file with antoher user, than the msgbox contains the appdata path of other user and not the current logon user.