# Executing Java program as administrator

Tags: java, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

```
Set UAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application")  
UAC.ShellExecute "C:\Users\Biebs\Desktop\New folder\Loader.bat", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1
```

I'm trying to execute a Java file as an administrator, this one requires a terminal so it will be a little harder then simply running the Jar in an administrator's cmd.

I have a Java loader that executes the class file to the java program. I tried to run the loader as an Administrator, it gives me a 'cannot find or load main class' error. So I found a VBS script that would execute the batch as an administrator, however this still didn't work. However just to clarify, when I run the loader as a non administrator it works perfectly. How can I execute a java program, that requires a terminal, so I can have administrator rights.

Comment: Have not tried any Java class with PsExec, take a look at this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515854), it may help you.

Comment: @patrick Does it only grant admin privileges when no user is specified?

Comment: @impinball I believe Yes (only if the current user is in Administrators Group on that computer or in a Group that is Administrators).

Comment: You haven't specified the path parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Java: run as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator) helped to solve my problem. Just make sure to add the Elevate.exe into the folder of your source (where the .class and .java files are), afterwards all administrator commands can be executed by using this code...

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Elevate.exe yourcommand");
```

Thanks to user mathd for posting that...

The elevate program can be found at http://jpassing.com/2007/12/08/launch-elevated-processes-from-the-command-line/ . Thanks to all who helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a runas program. Run without parameters for help.

```
HelpMsg = vbcrlf & "  ShVerb" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  David Candy 2014" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Lists or runs an explorer verb (right click menu) on a file or folder" & vbcrlf  & vbcrlf & "    ShVerb <filename> [verb]" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Used without a verb it lists the verbs available for the file or folder" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The program lists most verbs but only ones above the first separator" & vbcrlf & "  of the menu work when used this way" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The Properties verb can be used. However the program has to keep running" & vbcrlf & "  to hold the properties dialog open. It keeps running by displaying" & vbcrlf & "  a message box."

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag = WScript.Arguments 
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Ag.count = 0 then 
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - No file specified"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    ElseIf Ag.count = 1 then 
        If LCase(Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/")) = "/h" or Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/") = "/?" then 
            wscript.echo HelpMsg 
            wscript.quit
        End If
    ElseIf Ag.count > 2 then 
        wscript.echo vbcrlf & "  ShVerb - To many parameters" & vbcrlf & "  Use quotes around filenames and verbs containing spaces"  & vbcrlf
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    If fso.DriveExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
'       Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.self
        msgbox ag(0)
    ElseIf fso.FolderExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    ElseIf fso.fileExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    Else
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - " & Ag(0) & " not found"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    Set objVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs

    'If only one argument list verbs for that item

    If Ag.count = 1 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If len(cmd) <> 0 then CmdList = CmdList & vbcrlf & replace(cmd.name, "&", "") 
        Next
        wscript.echo mid(CmdList, 2)

    'If two arguments do verbs for that item

    ElseIf Ag.count = 2 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If lcase(replace(cmd, "&", "")) = LCase(Ag(1)) then 
                wscript.echo Cmd.doit 
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    'Properties is special cased. Script has to stay running for Properties dialog to show.
        If Lcase(Ag(1)) = "properties" then
            WSHShell.AppActivate(ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties")
            msgbox "This message box has to stay open to keep the " & ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties dialog open."
        End If  
    End If
```