# How to run a batch file as administrator from a java program

Tags: batch-file, cmd, administrator

I am creating a hotspot software for which I need to run a batch file as administrator from a java program. The batch file contains the following two commands:

netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=name key=password

netsh wlan start hostednetwork

name and password are taken as input from the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As *capturesteve* has written - run the app as administrator. You can use for example `cmd.exe` under Windows. If you run the cmd.exe with administrator privileges, everything what will be started from this "administrator" cmd.exe will inherit the rights of his owner. It's a universal principle in Windows (and not only in Windows).

Run the cmd.exe as administrator and start the java app from it:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-8&faq=7

+

[Java: run as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator)

[Executing Java program as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21539307/executing-java-program-as-administrator)

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to run the java application itself as sudo.

Comment: What do you mean by running the java application as sudo?

Comment: running as a sudo is a Linux term. It means running as an administrator in Windows